# Take records where 2 variables are met with a count

Tags: sql, postgresql

**So I have the following table:**

| User | Date | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020-01-05 | Desktop |
| A | 2020-07-01 | Mobile |
| A | 2020-09-01 | Desktop |
| A | 2020-12-31 | Email |
| B | 2020-03-01 | Mobile |
| B | 2020-11-05 | Email |

**But what I want to do is:**

1. Take the minimum (first) date for each user AND minimum (first) record for each user where the type Type = Mobile
2. And then count all subsequent records for each user regardless of the type and/or date

**Below is an example of what I want to achieve using PostgreSQL:**

| User | min_date | min_type | count_of_subsequent_records |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020-07-01 | Mobile | 2 |
| B | 2020-03-01 | Mobile | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . Use window functions to get the minimum date and then user aggregation:

```
select user, date, 'mobile', count(*) - 1
from (select t.*,
             min(date) filter (where type = 'mobile') over (partition by user) as min_mobile_date
      from t
     ) t
where date >= min_mobile_date
group by user, date;
```

Another way of doing this uses `distinct on`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user order by date desc) - 1 as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where type = 'mobile'
order by user, date;
```

This uses `row_number()` to count the rows in descending order.  So the number assigned to each row is the number of rows on or after that row.